# issue while printing the values passed via command line arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in c using command line arguments & array pointers...

My goal is to find the values which we are passing via command line argument.

Seperating those values using strtok by having  , as a seperator

But i'm getting segmentation fault after 2 iteratios.i don't understand where i'm making making mistake.

Could someone help me to get rid of this issue?

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        char *str[] = {};
        char *string = argv[1];
        const char s[2] = ",";
        char *token = "";

        int i = 0,j = 0,k = 0,l = 0,m = 0;

        token = strtok(string, s);
        while( token != NULL )
        {
                str[i] = token;
                printf("str[%d]= %s\n",i,str[i]);
              i++;
              token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

bash-3.2$ ./code hi,bye,hello,car

str[0]= hi

str[1]= bye

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `char *str[] = {};` --> `char *str[strlen(argv[1])/2+1];`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated enough memory to store the tokenized strings in `str`.

Change the line

```
char *str[] = {};
```

to

```
char *str[ARRAY_SIZE] = {};
```

and define `ARRAY_SIZE` to be a value large enough to hold all the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variable str was not allocated any memory. You try to store a series of `char *` pointers in it but there's no memory where to store them.

A quick fix would be to define a certain number of slots:
`char *str[10];`

In the while loop you should check that you don't try to store more than 10 pointers.